# How to make Twitter Spaces audio come out of the Lightning port?

Tags: iphone, audio, twitter

I plug a Lightning-to-3.5mm adapter into my iPhone. And plug that into a stereo or computer or whatever.

Then open Twitter on the phone and play videos.

The audio comes out of the stereo or records into the computer.

Now start a Twitter Spaces.

It switches some audio profile or something and the audio comes out of the speaker on the phone. I don't want that. I want the audio to continue coming out through the Lightning port. How do I do that?

Comment: What happens when you bring up the output selector (if spaces doesn't have a button, use the button in control center, top-right of the media tile)